# How to make this layout in Listview like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Did this kind of listview possible in the android?
i am trying that view using following code
also use sticky header but not result.

`'public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.aboveLayout);
    //do render.
}`'

i am wanting follwing result

[image]

Comment: Check this https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Comment: you need to create a custom layout for your listview.

Comment: yes it is possible.Sort the arraylist and place it in the custom layout.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders), which is designed for this kind of layouts.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Linearlayout>
    <TextView />
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
</Linearlayout>
```

in your ListAdapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.aboveLayout);
    //do render.
}
```